# The outline of my object is really hard to see

Tags: interface, wireframe

I have been trying to follow Blender Guru's guide on how to model a chair, and it involves using reference images. When I apply a subdivision modifier to my model and try to edit it in wireframe mode, I cannot see the outline of where the subdivision is happening, because its light gray and blends in with the reference image. I can see it against the dark workspace background though. In the tutorial video, his outline is completely black. I have no clue on what is causing this, because I don't remember fiddling with such a setting. Really want to continue but this is very frustrating and i can't seem to find an awnser to this. [image]

Answer (score 1):

These bright lines are additional geometry generated by modifier. It is bright (or invisible on white) to give you a feedback of current silhouette, but mainly keep user focused on real topology ...

[image]

If you want to see them all disable **Optimal Display** in modifier properties ...

[image]

[image]

Alternatively ... If you want to keep *Optimal Display* ON you can enhanced your view by switching to *Solid View* mode, but with X-Ray enabled (icon next to *Wire View* mode).

Comment: I have optimal display off and it does show the outline when I look at it with object mode, but when I want to edit it in wireframe mode the outline becomes invisible against the background. The solid view mode with x-ray is also very bright and hard to see against the background.

Comment: Sorry now I noticed it ... Have you tried another blender version? Please share your file via https://blend-exchange.com ... it is weird, lines you are mentioning are those I described ... so it doesn't make a sense. Thanks you

Comment: It was working before when i tried to do the same thing, but I forgot to save and my power went out so I lost all the progress. When I tried to redo it the lines just don't appear the same. I tried to reset to default setting, but that didn't have an effect either. I might just have to restart my PC or something.

Comment: What happen in new blend file with default Cube and SubSurf modifier ... can you reproduce the issue? Or in your issued file delete modifier and add again. BTW under Viewport Overlays > Geometry you can change Opacity, but it hides real geometry and keeps only light grey outline.

Comment: I really don't know anymore. It still happens in new file with default cube. The opacity is 100% and I haven't changed it. Might have to try and reinstall blender I guess.

Comment: Okay nevermind its still broken after reinstall with completely default settings.

Comment: By "Reset to Default" do you mean "Load Factory Settings", right? Have you tried a different version of blender as I asked in my first comment? Anyway you can search in bug reports if already there, if not try to report (go to Blender menu > Help > ... just to be clear Optional Display on/off does nothing, right?

Comment: Yes, the load factory settings didn't change anything. I tried downloading 3.1 and it works perfectly on that, but whatever I do I can't seem to get it to work on 3.2. It worked before, but after the power cutoff It seems it changed the setting on its own and is bugged now. I guess i will use 3.1 for now, but its still quite annoying that something like this can randomly happen. I will report this issue.